# Learning word embeddings by first learning character embeddings

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, word-embeddings

I was going through various papers for NLU applications(Natural Language Understanding).

There I have observed a common pattern that for a word embeddings, following 3 combinations are used (may be using concatenation or any other technique).

> 1. static word embedding (glove, word2vec)
> 2. word embeddings learnt from character embeddings
> 3. contextual word embedding

Currently I am implementing one of those papers and **I want to learn a word embedding from character embeddings** (I don't want to use pre-trained char-embeddings like FastText)

**learn character embeddings ---> learn word embeddings from char embedding --> train my custom task**

So I am thinking what is the best way to do this?

Let's say my data looks like this:

> row-1: What a sunny day. Beautiful! I feel happy.

Our task is, we want find embeddings for each word which derived from char embedding.

**approach-1]  use char level CNN (1ConvD)**

- Here features are nothing but unique characters in our data.
- I am assuming result of this step will be, I will have an embedding for each
  character.
- Then I will go word-by-word, e.g. 'sunny' --> 's'+'u'+'n'+'n'+'y' that is take
  a sum/max/avg of char embeddings to get a word embeddings.

  However this last step doesn't sound correct wrt backtracking operation. It feels disconnected from model chain.
  What am I missing here?

**approach-2] Use Bi-Dir LSTM**
Something like this as described in this [Blog](https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/sequence-tagging-with-tensorflow.html):

[image]

But few things are not clear from this:

1. **"What a sunny day"**
   Here how would I know **word boundary?** In above picture there was just 1 word so concatenation was easy.
2. Since we are using hidden state as char embedding that means for same letter (e.g. 'C'), embedding will be different in 2 different words. Is my understanding correct?